# Jquery star rating not working in Firefox & chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

i am using star rating plugin from https://github.com/ripter/jquery.rating, and using select box code as

```
<select name="Rating">
    <option value="6">1</option>
    <option value="7">2</option>
    <option value="8">3</option>
    <option value="9">4</option>
    <option value="10">5</option>
</select>
```

And javascript code is like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.rating.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("select[name='Rating']").addClass('rating');
            $(".rating").rating();
            $("select[name=Rating]").bind("change", function(){
                alert( $("select[name=Rating]").val() );
            });
        });     
    </script>
```

And am using the same CSS available with the plugin. Here am trying to alert the selected value. Its working fine with IE8, But not working with Firefox & chrome. in firefox & chrome alert value is always 6. I am not getting what is the problem. Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try including JQuery Migrate into your project and see if it's works

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/